# Как менять фон в зависимости от погоды?

Tags: kotlin, api, openweathermap

Создаю приложение текущей погоды с помощью api openweathermap на kotlin и хотел бы чтобы фон менялся в зависимости от состояния погоды, например зимой, когда идет снег, фон был снежным(из моей папки drawable) и тд. Я вроде все подготовил, но когда добавляю функцию смены фона, все зависит от id погоды который мне необходимо написать, а я хочу это все автоматизировать по погоде.

Ниже функция которая должна менять фон в зависимости от id. Но мне надо сделать так, чтобы она автоматизировалась

```
private fun updateUI(id: Int){
    if(id in 200..232){
        binding.ivWeatherBg.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm_bg)
        binding.ivWeatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm)

    } else if (id in 300..321){
        binding.ivWeatherBg.setImageResource(R.drawable.drizzle_bg)
        binding.ivWeatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.drizzle)

    } else if (id in 500..531){
        binding.ivWeatherBg.setImageResource(R.drawable.drizzle_bg)
        binding.ivWeatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.rain)

    } else if (id in 600..620){
        binding.ivWeatherBg.setImageResource(R.drawable.snow_bg)
        binding.ivWeatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.snow)

    } else if (id in 701..781){
        binding.ivWeatherBg.setImageResource(R.drawable.mist_bg)
        binding.ivWeatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.mist)

    } else if (id == 800){
        binding.ivWeatherBg.setImageResource(R.drawable.clear_bg)
        binding.ivWeatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.clear)

    } else {
        binding.ivWeatherBg.setImageResource(R.drawable.clouds_bg)
        binding.ivWeatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.clouds)
    }
}
```